# move the content in the description product tab

Tags: magento2

set of data which want to move on the Description product tab

move the stock information in the description tab in

Comment: can you possible add the screenshot.so i wiil understand

Answer (score 0):

I try to interpret your request:
in your custom theme create this file `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view_type_simple.xml`

The content should be the following

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="product.info.simple" destination="product.info.description" before="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

I'm not sure that it's what you are looking for. If not, please try to be more specific.
Hope this helps

Comment: I have try this , bit is not working